# How to use SQL Query with hyphen in Collection name?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Does anyone know how to use a SQL query on a CosmosDB Collection that has a hyphen in the name? For example

```
SELECT * FROM product-group where product-group.id = "3829503"
```

I've see that properties can be accessed using the [""] syntax but haven't seen any solutions for the actual collection name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you query via DocumentDB SQL, you don't need to specify the exact collection name; you're really specifying an alias in your query.

In the Query Explorer (via the portal), all queries are done by first selecting a collection. At that point, use a simple alias to query. For example, here is a query against a collection called `sample-data` (as selected in the "Collections" dropdown), but I don't need to specify the actual collection name in the query. I simply use `mycollection` as an alias for `sample-data`:

[image]

And in code, the SDK call includes both a database parameter and a collection parameter, again obviating the need for the actual collection name in the query. For example, the same query, called from c#, might look something like this:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyObject>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("mydb", "sample-data"),
            "SELECT * FROM mycollection WHERE mycollection.id = '3829503'");
```

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @rob - This answer *needed* the screenshot, as I'm doing it to illustrate how to do this in the portal specifically, the key part being the collection drop-down. And below it, the non-image code in an SDK call.

Comment: you're right, you always specify a collection whether its the SDK or Query explorer so you can just use whatever alias to in the query, thanks!