# How to query Cosmos DB with dashes in container name

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

In my database I have a container named "freedom-fighters".

Doing  `SELECT * FROM [freedom-fighters]` does not work. Neither does `SELECT * FROM "freedom-fighters"`, nor `SELECT * FROM ["freedom-fighters"]`, nor anything else I have tried.

I am working in the web gui.

Comment: My solution was that a query runs in the context of a container and I, hence, don't have to (cannot?) specify container.

Answer (score 2):

When you query via Core/SQL API, you don't need to specify the exact collection name.  In the Portal you can  use a simple alias to query. For example,

```
SELECT * FROM c
```

Cosmos DB will know which one you are targeting already and c will be something like an alias.

Comment: FYI the question is an exact duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719930/how-to-use-sql-query-with-hyphen-in-collection-name/46721189#46721189) - please vote accordingly.

Comment: Agree. I have read that question but didn't thinkt it applied to me. After finding the answer I understand it does. My bad.